# Determine if super() is called from inherited class

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to determine that the inheriting class has bothered to call `super()` in JavaScript?

```
function A() {

  A.prototype.isInitialized = function() {
      // what can be checked to see if B bothered to called super()
  }  
}

class B extends A {
   //constructor() {
   // didn't call super()
   //}
}
```

Assume B didn't have its own constructor. Does it just use A's constructor thus effectively having called super by default?

Comment: when is `isInitialized` called?

Comment: I suppose after B is constructed?

Comment: Well it is not called automatically. Can you add example code that creates an object, executes the method, and show the output you expect? Maybe also add the case when `super` is called.

Comment: Is there a reason why you mixed the constructor syntax (for A) with the class syntax (for B)?

Comment: Yeah, I was just trying to figure out what happens when B is constructed without it's own constructor in ES6.

Comment: Don't test whether anything was called. Just test whether `this` looks like what you need (with initialised properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to create an instance of *B* without also calling *A's* constructor (except if you don't use the object that would be created for you, and return another object, see further down).

If you don't specify a constructor for class *B*, then silently one is created for you that looks like this (in your case there are no arguments):

```
constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
}
```

If you explicitly create a constructor for *B*, and don't return an object, then you *must* call `super` in it, otherwise no instance of *B* can be created. The following will produce an error:

```js
function A() {
    console.log('hi');
}

class B extends A { 
    constructor() {
        // no call to super is made
    }
}

var b = new B(); // Reference Error: `this` is not defined
```

#### Using return

If however, you ignore the object that would be created for you (the context, `this`), don't reference `this`, and return another object, then the constructor of the parent will not be called:

```js
function A() {
  console.log('hi');
  this.isInitialised = true;
}

class B extends A { 
  constructor() {
    return Object.create(B.prototype);
  }
}

var b = new B();
console.log(b instanceof B, b instanceof A, b.isInitialised); // true, true, undefined
```

Here we use `Object.create` to create an instance of *B's* prototype, which is an instance of *A*, but *A's* constructor does not get executed. See the output to interpret the result.

#### Conclusion

So, whether you define a constructor on *B* or not, in all valid cases where you don't return an object, the constructor of *A* is called.

When using `return` in *B's* constructor, it is possible create an object that still is an instance of *A*, but where its constructor is not called. You can use a property in instances of *A* to indicate whether the constructor ran or not.

Comment: You could use `class B extends A { constructor() { return Object.create(B.prototype); } }`. You just cannot use `this` in the constructor and have to explicitly `return` something if you don't call `super()`.

Comment: Ah yes, an explicit return: didn't think of that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, no constructor is the same as a constructor that just calls `super`, so you don't have to worry about having an uninitialized parent.

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.isInit = true
  }

   isInitialized() {
     return !!this.isInit
   }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
}

class C extends A {
}


b = new B()
console.log(b.isInitialized())

c = new C()
console.log(c.isInitialized())
```

Comment: I assume that also means that 'this' has been bound in that case.

Comment: `this` has been bound to what? Where ?